# Get all attributes from XML

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have an XML like this:

```
<list>
    <sublist id="a">
        <item name="name1">
            <property1>a</property1>
            <property2>b</property2>
        </item>
        <item name="name2">
            <property1>c</property1>
            <property2>d</property2>
        </item>
    </sublist>
    <sublist id="b">
        [...more XML here...]
    </sublist>
</list>
```

I'm trying to get only the sublist id elements from all the sublist, so I can return it in a new XML like this one:

```
<list>
    <sublist id="a">
    </sublist>
    <sublist id="b">
    </sublist>
    [...moreXML here....]
</list>
```

I'm trying this

```
Dim xPath As String = "//list"
xmlItems = xmlData.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode(xPath)
```

But obviously I am getting the entire XML. How can I return that new XML?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear if this is what you are asking for, but this will give you the list of all of the `id` values:

```
Dim ids As New List(Of String)()
For Each i As XmlNode In xmlData.SelectNodes("//list/sublist/@id")
    ids.Add(i.Value)
Next
```

However, I would recommend that you also consider using XSLT for this task.  XSLT is great for transforming XML from one format to another.  For instance, this XSLT script will transform the XML you gave to the example desired output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/list">
    <list>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="sublist"/>
    </list>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/list/sublist">
    <sublist>
      <xsl:attribute name="id">
        <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
    </sublist>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you, the first one should work fine for me. I will investigate about XSLT.